# Applying MONAI transforms to sequences of images uniformly

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, pytorch, data-augmentation

I am working with a medical dataset in which each datapoint is a sequence of 10 images. I want to apply MONAI transforms (Rand2DElastic, RandRotate, RandZoom, RandGaussianNoise) to these sequences for augmentation. These transforms should be applied randomly to each sequence, however each image in a given sequence should have the exact same transforms for consistency purposes. Is there already existing functionality to do so? If there is not, is there a good way of doing it?
Data is stored as an np array of shape (n, 10, 3, 128, 128)
Thanks!

```
images = [Image.open(os.path.join(self.root_dir, image_path)) for image_path in sequence_path]
images = [np.transpose(np.array(image), (2,0,1)) for image in images] 

        if self.augment:
            augment_transforms = Compose([
                Rand2DElastic(prob=0.6, spacing=(30, 30), magnitude_range=(0.1, 0.3)),
                RandRotate(range_x=np.pi / 60, prob=0.2, keep_size=True),
                RandZoom(min_zoom=0.8, max_zoom=1.5, prob=0.6),
                RandGaussianNoise(prob=0.5, mean=0, std=0.01)
            ])
            images = augment_transforms({"image": np.array(images)})["image"]
            print(images)
```

This is what I tried so far, but didn't give results I needed

Answer (score 0):

i'm also working with MONAI right now. Maybe you can use the [dictionary-transforms](https://docs.monai.io/en/latest/transforms.html#dictionary-transforms). I use them to do the same transformation on an image and the corresponding segmentation mask [Tutorial for 3D seg](https://github.com/Project-MONAI/tutorials/blob/main/3d_segmentation/spleen_segmentation_3d.ipynb). In your case, you should input your 10 Image series.
Maybe another option is to concat your 10 objects to one object with one more dimension.

Comment: Please do not post answers where the main content is linked on another webpage. [edit] your post and summarize the most important points on those webpages and you can still leave the link as support for more details.